# Convergence of roots in the unit disk of $\mathbb C$

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

Let $(z_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of complex numbers such that $z_n^n=z$ for each $n\in\mathbb N$, where $z\in\mathbb C$ is a fixed complex number on the closed unit disk: $|z|\leq 1$. I want to show the following: $$\exp(z_n-1)=z_n+o(n^{-1}),$$ that is, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\{n[\exp(z_n-1)-z_n]\}=0$$ *without* using complex logarithms. Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $z=1$ and we choose the sequence $\{z_n\}$ such that $z_n=-1$ whenever $n$ is even, then 
$$ n(\exp(z_n-1)-z_n)=n(e^{-2}+1) $$
whenever $n$ is even.

Therefore the sequence $\{n(\exp(z_n-1)-z_n)\}$ does not necessarily tend to zero, at least not without some further assumptions on the $z_n$.

Comment: Indeed, more stringent assumptions are needed to ensure the desired conclusion. I will think about it. Thank you.